# "Manifest file is invalid"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am updating my Chrome extension's manifest version.

In my local machine, it works.

When I try to install via the test group, it shows the “Manifest file is invalid” error.

Here's my manifest:

```
{
  "name": "MercadoLivre - Sugestões de busca",
  "description" : "Busque no MercadoLivre direto da barra de endereços",

  "version": "0.12",
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "icons": { "128": "logo.png" },

  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },

  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'",

  "omnibox": { "keyword" : "ml" },

  "permissions": [
    "http://suggest.mlapps.com/jm/*"
  ]
}
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Try to remove special characters like `õ` and `ç`

Comment: @alfasin It didn't work. It was working with them and in my local machine it is ok.

Comment: what about the developer-folder path, does it contain special characters ?

Comment: This problem appears when I try to install it via the plugin page on the Chrome Web Store, not locally.

Comment: The manifest file is correct. Are you sure that all dependencies (`background.html`, `manifest.json` and `logo.png`) are contained in the crx?

Comment: @RobW They are in the zip file. I am not using crx.

Comment: Did you package and publish the zip file in [this way](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/packaging.html)? If yes, would you like to share the link, for debugging?

Comment: @RobW I simply packaged as a zip and it always worked. Here is the [zip](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/30410/src.zip). If you give me your email, I can add you in the user group so you'll be able to try to install it via the Chrome Web Store.

Comment: @PedroMenezes What tool did you use to create the zip file (on a Mac)? When I use `7z l src.zip`, I see a bunch of directories like `src`, `__MACOSX`, `__MACOSX/src`. Either use a proper zip creator (http://7-zip.org/) or use the built-in packer in Chrome (at `chrome://extensions/`, Developer mode -> Pack extension).

Comment: @RobW I did that using 'zip' in CLI. Only the necessary files are in the zip and I keep getting "Manifest file is invalid".

Comment: @PedroMenezes In OSX, such directories are automatically hidden. I suggest to [download 7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/), and add the files manually: `7z a src.zip background.html ga.js json2.js logo.png manifest.json`. PS. Why did you include `json2.js` in your extension? JSON is natively supported in Chrome.

Comment: @robw I deleted json2. I was doing another thing. I zipped with 'zip' and I can assure you there aren't Mac OS files [anymore](http://paste.org/51532).

Comment: @PedroMenezes Well, is it working? (It should). If it's still not working, The `__MACOSX` etc directories are still there.

Comment: @robw It isn't. Same message. And I used another program to compress the source (again with only the necessary files). You can check it out [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/30410/src.zip) :(

Comment: @PedroMenezes Works fine here. Did you really upload it to the Web store?

Comment: Yes, the upload is ok. The problem appears when I try to install it via the Web Store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logging out and in worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

For me, the error was a result of updating my plugin and then trying to install it immediately. When I waited a few minutes, the error no longer appeared. The Google Extension servers are probably out of sync for a few minutes during the time it takes to propagate the new update.

Comment: I think that this is what happened to me too. Thought something odd was happening when after uploading a new version with version 0.0.0.9, the Chrome Web Store popup still had it at 0.0.0.8 (but the last updated date was correct). After waiting a minute or so, it worked.

Comment: I don't even want to share how much time I ended up wasting because of my impatience :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. Restarting worked for me. I got the idea for it from a Chromium [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=103281). Though sometimes it is an actual packaging problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error too , I think maybe your resources under a SkyDrive folder or some team code Management soft folder . Try to copy the resources to another path, such as desktop. package your plugin with the new path , then your may resolve it !